# What are $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: notation

What are $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I've seen them referred to, I'm guessing they refer to a plane an a space that can be defined in Cartesian coordinates in 2 and 3 dimensions respectively, and the coordinates are in the set of real numbers.

Comment: For the double R, use \mathbb{R}. Also yes, you are right. $\mathbb{R}^2$ refers to the whole 2D plane where points have an $x-$ and $y-$ coordinate, while $\mathbb{R}^3$ refers to the whole 3D plane where points have an $x-$, $y-$ and $z-$ coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers. For example $(1,0,-2)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

There is a [Wikipedia article on real coordinate space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space).

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers.

$\mathbb{R}^2 = \{(x,y) \,\,|\,\, x\in \mathbb{R} ,\, y\in \mathbb{R}\}$

$\mathbb{R}^3 = \{(x,y,z) \,\,|\,\, x\in \mathbb{R} ,\, y\in \mathbb{R},\, z\in \mathbb{R}\}$

The geometric properties depend on the extra structures.